# chrome.wallpaper.setWallpaper not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I'm still learning about chrome extensions/apps and I have this problem with the chrome.wallpaper api. I'm trying to change the background to another one but it won't. Yes, I am running on chrome os version 43.

This is my code:

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
  chrome.wallpaper.setWallpaper({
    "url": "file:///home/chronos/u-f083140cd056ce74510f1290350a468fee3a9377/Downloads/1080bokeh.jpg",
    "layout": "CENTER_CROPPED",
    "filename": "1080bokeh"
  }, function() {});

});
```

I have checked that the file location exists.

On the console I am getting this:

```
    Unchecked runtime.lastError while running wallpaper.setWallpaper: Downloading wallpaper 1080bokeh.jpg failed. The response code is -1.
at chrome-extension://jiojpobpcbdplpiiallkhpehcdohgfij/background.js:17:20
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you're not allowed to point to `file://` urls in Chrome extensions. Try putting the image in the extension's folder and reference it relative to the extension's root directory.

Comment: Moved the image to the extensions directory and set "url" to "1080bokeh.jpg". Now it says that URL is invalid on the console.

Comment: What if you try hosting it somewhere?

Comment: Just replaced url with a random url linking to jpg image. Now getting response code 407. I googled that response code and turns out to a proxy authentication error. It is true that my chromebook uses a proxy since it's organisation-issued but that should not be the problem since i've already logged in to the proxy.

Comment: According to the docs, you should be able to set a http url. The docs also state that you need to add "wallpaper" as a permission, have you done that? https://developer.chrome.com/apps/wallpaper

Comment: Yes, I have set the "wallpaper"  permission on the manifest.json file. Still the same error. I think this is just a network issue since I'm using a proxy.